# Having problem when i try to import json_serializable package

Tags: android, json, flutter, package

I am pretty beginner in Flutter development. I follow the flutter document to understand the development environment and techniques.

So, i am trying to understand working with json data and serialise deserialise it. I use the package `json_serializable` as it is recommended in the formal doc as well.

the problem is that i can't run the terminal code that the document mentions 
[here](https://flutter.io/docs/development/data-and-backend/json#one-time-code-generation)

Whenever i try use `flutter packages pub run build_runner build` command , I get

```
bash: flutter: command not found` result.
```

Any idea what may cause this ?

Comment: Try just `flutter`. Seems you don't have the path to the `bin/` sub-dir of the Flutter install directory set. Like shown in https://flutter.io/docs/get-started/install/macos#get-the-flutter-sdk

Comment: Are you using macOS?

Comment: Yes, i use macOS. Well, i think i am having problem with the path as you mention above. Even though i have followed the steps in that link when i install flutter , i couldn't figure out how to change the path in deed.

Comment: Flutter SDK is located under User/user/  , i also succeeded to run my app. It works fine. But, i am still having a problem in this topic somehow.

Comment: What path did you add to `PATH` environment variable? If you enter `echo $PATH` does it contain the path to `flutter/bin`?

Comment: Well, It does , even though i get really interesting nested file path when i run `echo $PATH` `User/mymac/flutter/bin:User/mymac/flutter/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin` Do i need to tidy this mess ?

Comment: You added it twice. That shouldn't cause such troubles (not ideal though). What do you get when you run `~/flutter/bin/flutter`?

Comment: I don't copy paste all output here . That command gives me a command list related with Flutter;  Common commands, Global options, Available commands etc.

Comment: That looks good. I think the issue is the missing `/` at the beginning of `User/mymac/flutter/bin` in your `PATH` variable.

Comment: So, is there any way to get rid of that duplicate in the path ? Also, i wonder how can i add that `/` to my path. Thanks for helping btw.

Comment: If you add it with leading `/` when you follow https://flutter.io/docs/get-started/install/macos#update-your-path and close and reopen your terminal window, you should have the correct path and also only once.